# How to properly rasterize unregular data points on EASE2 grid?

Tags: r, r-raster

I was given data with 3 columns (lon, lat, data) which I would like to turn into a SpatRaster.

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21

df <- read.csv("data.csv")

head(df)
#>        lon      lat mean_daily_par_mol
#> 1 -7.52993 61.91259          0.5463984
#> 2 -7.16531 61.77965          0.5635693
#> 3 -6.80426 61.64570          0.6404579
#> 4 -6.44676 61.51075          0.6602439
#> 5 -6.09277 61.37483          0.6801313
#> 6 -5.74228 61.23794          0.6358355
```

Unfortunately, the data is not on a regular grid, so I can create a raster directly. [The data is on the MODIS ISIN grid](https://landweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QS/new/pages.cgi?name=help&sensor=MODIS&fileName=prod_format).

```r
rast(df)
#> Error: [raster,matrix(xyz)] x cell sizes are not regular


e <- ext(c(min(df$lon), max(df$lon), min(df$lat), max(df$lat)))
e
#> SpatExtent : -180, 179.69196, 60.00299, 89.41164 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

r <- rast(e, ncols = 100, nrows = 100)

r <- rasterize(
  as.matrix(df[c("lon", "lat")]),
  r,
  df$mean_daily_par_mol,
  fun = mean,
  na.rm = TRUE
)

plot(r)
```

[image]

Obviously, changing `ncols` and `nrows` considerably influence how the raster is created.

```r
r <- rast(e, ncols = 300, nrows = 300)

r <- rasterize(
  as.matrix(df[c("lon", "lat")]),
  r,
  df$mean_daily_par_mol,
  fun = mean,
  na.rm = TRUE
)

plot(r)
```

[image]

My question is how can I find the *optimal* `ncols` and `nrows` so there is approximately 1 values per pixel. The ultimate goal being to reproject this data onto the EASE2 grid.
The data is available [here](https://easyupload.io/ljuugx)

<sup>Created on 2022-05-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The points (6) of your example are about 40 x 30 km apart. If they describe a grid (e. g. as centroids), that's your approximate cell size (width decreasing with latitude because sinusoidal). You could easily "warp" the ISIN grid polygons (as vector, not raster) to the desired EASE2 (see e.g. the bounding boxes of the 10 deg grid here: from taking https://modis-land.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdf/sn_bound_10deg.txt) and rasterize. Only that the 30x40 km don't correspond to any MODIS resolution I could find, incl. the 9x9 km size of PAR you seem to be processing. Could you share a link to the (meta)data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If that can help, this code can be used to convert from bin to latitude (oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/staff/norman/swreadl3b/swreadl3b.c). See also appendix A here (https://oceancolor.gsfc.nasa.gov/SeaWiFS/TECH_REPORTS/PreLPDF/PreLVol32.pdf).  I think the data is MODIS l3bin: https://oceandata.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/MODIS-Terra/L3BIN